# Ruby: Is it possible to have a for loop that increases more than one at a time?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

For example:

`for(int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2)`

I could use a while loop or check if i % 2 == 0, but I was wondering if there wasn't a way to do it with the for loop. I could also use `for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)` and multiply i by 2, but that doesn't seem right either. I'm just wondering if there is a simple, straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
(0...100).step(2) do |i|
  # loop body
end
```

Comment: out of interest, how would you translate `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i *= 2)` then?

Comment: @oedo:  `i=0;while(true):`

Comment: @oedo: Not an exact translation, but Ruby 1.9 Enumerators are handy for such iterations: http://gist.github.com/365235